# MS Word - Lock one column on first page?

Tags: ms-word

We have a company 'letterhead' template with all company info in a left column/sidebar.  I'd like to lock that section for editing, but still retain the option to edit and/or mail merge the rest of the document as normal.  I've tried the Restrict Editing feature, but that seems like the opposite function of what I need;  I'd like to specify a section that is not editable, as opposed to a section that is.

The main problem is that the mailmerge/add-envelope function is disabled when Restrict Editing is on, but also adding a section break to a second page (to change to a single-column format on subsequent pages) isn't allowed either.

I've considered just creating an image of the left sidebar, but that seems hacky. Does anyone have any other suggestions on this one?
Much appreciated
--michael~

Comment: Actually, an image isn't a bad idea... Another possibility is to use a Content Control with the option to not allow editing or deletion activated. The tricky part is the left-hand column bit - it would have to be in a table or text box and no way to lock those. If the template has different first-page for header/footer putting it in the header/footer gives you a certain amount of protection against accidental manipulation.

Comment: Please note that non-programming questions are technically off-topic on StackOverflow and should be asked in end-user oriented venues...

Comment: I appreciate the response.. asking it here was a last-ditch hope.. technically, the solution could be in code tho, so.. kinda sorta still within the realm of 'okay'..  :p

Comment: Which is why I posted the "working" comment before the "administrative" one :-) Any reaction to that first comment?

Comment: I opted for a combo of ideas, and used your last suggestion to bury an image in the first-page header.  The table/content control seemed too complicated.   Yes, it's a hacky solution, but with the wrapping options to prevent text over the image, it's like a margin without having to set them, so I can get rid of the multi-column and Restrict Editing thing, and subsequent pages are completely normal without extra section break necessary.  I appreciate the responses.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome :-) If you type that up into an "Answer" we can up-vote it and (eventually) you can mark it as "the" answer. Forum administration likes that <g>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for a combo of ideas, and used your [Cindy] last suggestion to bury an image in the first-page header. The table/content control seemed too complicated. Yes, it's a hacky solution, but with the wrapping options to prevent text over the image, it's like a margin without having to set them, so I can get rid of the multi-column and Restrict Editing thing, and subsequent pages are completely normal without extra section break necessary. I appreciate the responses. Thanks!